# What is the convention to pluralize entities ending in 'y' in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This may be a simple and short question, but I couldn't find it anywhere and I am reluctant to just "test" it since the database I am working on is somehow important.

I was wondering what is the convention with Entities ending in letter 'y' when they should be pluralized. For example, if I have an entity named `Category`, should I pluralize it like `Categories` or `Categorys` if I want to follow entity framework conventions?

Comment: Probably a good idea to fire up another, less important database to test such matters. The journey is more educational than the destination.

Comment: It should be following the standard English language rules (of course if they didn't miss something) - see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/Pluralization/EnglishPluralizationService.cs#L820) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/Pluralization/EnglishPluralizationService.cs#L840)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'll be pluralized to `Categories`.

`y` will be pluralized to `ies`.

Comment: standard English language then. Thank you